# Stop .htaccess blocking cron jobs

Tags: php, security

I have a php script on my site that, when run, changes the 'Dog of the Day' on my home page. I have a cron job set up to run the script once a day, and everything works perfectly.

I've secured my 'scripts' directory with an .htaccess file, because if someone stumbles upon the php script, it'll be run, causing the 'Dog of the Day' to be updated.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

I changed the cron job to run every minute, but the .htaccess is blocking it, despite 127.0.0.1 being whitelisted. I changed 127.0.0.1 to my own ip, and I can access it, so it's not a problem with syntax.

Comment: Have you tried allowing the IP of your server? if your running the phpscript through a cronjob you are still requesting the URL right? So you need to allow your servers IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the script out of your DocumentRoot and into /opt/sitename or somewhere else. Allow it to modify files in your DocumentRoot, and don't worry about people stumbling across it at all.